Any working online WASM compilers in 2024?
I would like to experiment with WASM a bit, but I'd like to avoid going through the process of installing Emscripten, LLVM etc. So I thought, maybe I can find some online WASM compilers, where I could compile C code, and possibly download a .wasm file? And indeed, I found some, all listed here, but:

https://wasdk.github.io/WasmFiddle/ - 404s (https://wasmfiddle.com goes to a lander page, domain expired)
https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/ - if you paste code and hit Compile, it just waits forever
https://WebAssembly.studio also goes to lander page, domain expired

https://webassembly-studio.kamenokosoft.com/ does show a page, but trying to build "Hello World in C" project causes "Task build failed: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."



So is there any working compiler for C to WASM left online in 2024?

Yeah. All those sites are foobar'd.
